# Can Mercurial be integrated into Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, version-control, mercurial, tortoisehg

Is there a tool to integrate [Mercurial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercurial) into Visual Studio?

I am just curious. Mercurial is pretty nice, even with 'just' [TortoiseHG](http://tortoisehg.sourceforge.net), but integration with Visual Studio would be better.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[VisualHG](http://sharesource.org/project/visualhg/)

Way to go, me.  (Found the answer myself afterwards.  Oh well, someone might find this useful.)

Answer (score 1):

There is also [HgSccPackage](http://bitbucket.org/zzsergant/hgsccpackage/wiki/Home), which does not need TortoiseHG to work.